# Como obtener un objeto a traves de un ArrayList en Firebase

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, firebase

Estoy haciendo una app, y la tengo sinconizada con el `Real Time Database`. Un objeto contiene un campo que es de tipo `Arraylist`. Tengo que hacer una consulta por `orderByChild`. Esta consulta consiste en pasarle los elemento de otra lista, y devolver el que coincide con esos elementos de la otra lista. Como puedo hacer para que al realizar la consulta, no importe el orden de los elementos de la lista?

Una lista creada a partir de `idIngredinte` tendría que coincidir con `ingredientes`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola podrias tomarle una captura a tu base de datos para poderte ayudar de manera mas eficiente :D

Comment: Si ahora lo subo

Comment: podrias, comentar un ejemplo de lo que quieres :D

Comment: Por ejemplo, realizo la consulta pasando una lista con los ingredientes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (por idIngrdiente), y y como resultado me tendría que aparecer tortilla de patata porque tiene elementos en común de la lista ingrediente de receta.